# Trying to understand why class destructor is being called after assignment operator

Tags: c++, destructor

This was a homework assignment from last year that I decided to pop open and look through.  I ran through the debugger and noticed the destructor was being called at the end of an assignment operation (overloaded assignment).  Can anyone tell me why its being called?  I provided the full code so that it can be ran in a compiler (which may make it easier to answer the question), but my question is only about a very small portion of code.

In the driver file, there's a function called `void TestCopyConstructor()`.  In this function, there's an assignment operation `X = "0.12345";`.  This calls one of the overloaded assignment operator functions `MyFloat MyFloat::operator= (const char *Input)`.  This functions runs and at the end, of it, a copy constructor is called MyFloat `MyFloat::MyFloat(const MyFloat & RHS)`.  After this function, it returns back to the `void TestCopyConstructor()`, where the destructor is called.  I'm trying to understand why this destructor is being called.  I realize this is a lot of code, which is why I tried to walk through the specific area I'm confused on, as i wasn't sure how to make a stripped down, working version of this code.

DRIVER:

```
#include "MyFloatD.cpp"   //  Name of your class definition. Use pathname
//    if file is not in current working directory.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

void DisplayTestingOptions();
void GetChoice(char& Ch);

void TestInputOperator();
void TestAssignment();
void TestCopyConstructor();
void TestComparison();
void TestPlus();
void TestDestructor();

float CPU_Seconds();

//==============================  main   =================================

int main()
{
    char    Choice;

    do
    {

        DisplayTestingOptions();

        GetChoice(Choice);

        switch ( Choice )
        {
            case '1': TestCopyConstructor();
                break;
            case '2': TestAssignment();
                break;
            case '3': TestInputOperator();
                break;
            case '4': TestPlus();
                break;
            case '5': TestComparison();
                break;
            case '6': TestDestructor();
                break;
            case 'Q':      ;                           // Exit
        };
    }
    while ( Choice != 'Q' );

    return 0;
}

/***********************  SpaceBarToContinue    **************************

 Displays "Spacebar to continue" and returns 1 iff Spacebar pressed.

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
int SpaceBarToContinue(const char* Message = "  Spacebar continues this test")
{
    char Ch;

    cout << "\n------------------------------------------"
    <<   Message;
    Ch = cin.get();

    return ( Ch == ' ' );
}

/***********************  DisplayTestingOptions   ************************

 Displays a menu of choices.

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void DisplayTestingOptions()
{
    const char* TAB = "     ";  // Provides menu spacing

    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------"
    "------------------------------------\n\n";

    cout << TAB << "1)  Test copy constructor     ";

    cout << TAB << "2)  Test assignment operator \n";

    cout << TAB << "3)  Test >> input function    ";

    cout << TAB << "4)  Test + operator       \n";

    cout << TAB << "5)  Test == operator          ";

    cout << TAB << "6)  Test destructor       \n";

    cout << TAB << "Q)  Quit program\n\n";

    cout << "Choice? ";

}

/***********************  GetChoice   ************************************

 Reads a char from the keyboard, provides a redirectable echo and
 upcases the char.

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void GetChoice(char& Ch)
{
    cin >> Ch;
    Ch = toupper(Ch);

}

/*********************  TestInputOperator   ******************************

 Allows testing of the member functions ">>" of MyFloat.

 The insertion operator << is assumed to be correct.

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void TestInputOperator()
{
    MyFloat X;

    cout << "\n\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>  Testing input operator >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n";
    do
    {
        cout << "\nEnter MyFloat ==> ";
        cin  >> X;

        cout << "\nAfter the read,  X = '" << X << "'\n\n";
    }
    while ( SpaceBarToContinue() );

    if (cin.peek() != EOF)
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');

}


/*********************  TestAssignment   *********************************

 Allows testing of the member function "=" of MyFloat. If a deep copy
 assignment operator has not been written, the code below will give
 unexpected output.

 This routine assumes that input and output functions for MyFloats
 have been written and debugged.

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void TestAssignment()
{
    MyFloat X(10), Y(10);

    cout << "\n\n------------  Testing '='  for MyFloats   --------------------\n\n";

    X = "0.1234567890";

    Y = X;                // This must be a deep copy

    X = "0.0";            // Or this will change Y!

    cout << "\nAfter the assignments, X = \"0.1234567890\", Y = X, and X = 0.0, "
    << "Y = " << Y << endl;

}


/*********************  TestPlus   ***************************************

 Allows testing of the member function operator+. At the present time,
 it allows testing only of addition for MyFloats that have the default
 length.

 NOTE:  Calls two of the copy constructors. The copy constructor also
 needs to be working correctly for + to work.

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void TestPlus()
{
    MyFloat X(12), Y, Sum;


    cout << "\n\n++++++++++++++++  Testing \"+\"  for MyFloat  ++++++++++++++++\n"
    << "                  (Do not use leading zero)\n";
    do
    {
        cout << "\nEnter X  ==>   ";
        cin >> X;
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');         //  Discard all chars in input stream.

        cout << "\nEnter Y  ==> + ";
        cin >> Y;

        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');         //  Discard all chars in input stream.
        cout << "             ";

        for ( int k = 1; k <= X.Digits() + 3 || k <= Y.Digits() + 3 ; ++k )
            cout << '-';

        cout << "\n              ";

        Sum = X + Y;

        cout << Sum << "\n\n";

    }
    while ( SpaceBarToContinue() );
}


/*********************  TestCopyConstructor   ****************************

 Allows testing of the copy constructor that is called automatically
 under certain circumstances.

 Note that that the default constructor and the overloaded "=" operator
 must also be working properly.

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void TestCopyConstructor()
{
    MyFloat X;      // Default constructor called

    X = "0.12345";  // Overloaded "=" operator called

    MyFloat Y = X;  // Copy constructor called

    X = "0.0";

    cout << "\n\n============ Testing copy constructor  ================\n\n";
    cout << "NOTE: This function also calls default constructor and '='operator. \n\n\n";

    cout << "After 'X = 0.0',  Y = " << Y << "\nNote that Y should be 0.12345\n";

}

/*********************  TestComparison   *********************************

 Allows testing of the member function operator+. At the present time,
 it allows testing only of addition for MyFloats that have the default
 length.

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void TestComparison()
{
    MyFloat A, B, Sum;


    cout << "\n\n== == == == ==  Testing \"== \" for MyFloat  == == == == == \n\n";

    cout << "MyFloat variables have maximum length of " << A.MaxDigits() << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "\nEnter A  ==> ";
        cin  >> A;
        cout << "\nEnter B  ==> ";
        cin  >>  B;

        cout << "\n (A == B) is " << ((A == B) ? "TRUE " : "FALSE ") << endl;


    }
    while ( SpaceBarToContinue() );
}

/*********************  TestDestructor  **********************************

 Tests to see if the class destructor has been correctly written. If not
 this program may crash.

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void TestDestructor()
{

    const unsigned long REPETITIONS = 70000;

    for ( unsigned long N = 1;  N <= REPETITIONS;  ++N )
    {
        MyFloat X(10000);  // Create 1000 digit MyFloat
    }                 // X goes out of scope at each repetition

    // If the destructor is not correct, each repetition of the
    // loop above will caused some memory leak and the call to
    // new below will fail.

    int* A = new int[120];

    if ( A == NULL )
        cout << "\n\nYour memory has leaked away!\n";
    else
    {
        delete [] A;
        cout << "\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  destructor is OK!  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
    }
    SpaceBarToContinue(" spacebar to continue");
}
```

AND THE CLASS ITSELF:

```
/******************************************************************
----------------------Class Breakdown----------------------------

 Data Members:

 -enum (Default Size) sets the size of the MyFloat to 10 by default if no
            size is specified

 -Char *Number points at array being dynamically allocated in memory

 -NumberOfDigits represents the length of the current float

 -MaxNumberOfDigits represents the longest length that that particular 
            object can hold

 Member Functions:

 -MyFloat(const MyFloat & RHS) copy constructor allows usuer to initialize
        new object with another object, by placing it in the parameter list

 -MyFloat() is default constructor, initializes objects at MaxSize of 10

 -MyFloat(unsigned int Input) standard constructor allows user to create
        MyFloat of any size by placing a numerical value in the parameter list

 -int Digits() returns size of number currently stored in object

 -int MaxDigits() returns the maximum size allowed in current object

 -MyFloat operator= (const char *Input) overloaded assignemnt operator
        to work with setting an object equal to a literal string (X="0.004")

 -MyFloat operator= (const MyFloat &X) overloaded assignent operator to work 
        with setting an object equal to another object

 -int operator== (const MyFloat &x) overloaded comparison operator

 -MyFloat operator+ (MyFloat X) overloaded addition operator

 -int operator> (MyFloat x) overloaded greater than comparison operator

 -friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &Out, const MyFloat & X)
        overloaded insertion operator, so user can cout << X

 -friend istream& operator>> (istream &In, MyFloat & X)
        overloaded extraction operator, so user can cin >> X
 ********************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

class MyFloat
{
    enum {DefaultSizeTen=10};
    char *Number;

    int NumberOfDigits;
    int MaxNumberOfDigits;

public:

    ~MyFloat();

    MyFloat(const MyFloat & RHS);
    MyFloat();
    MyFloat(unsigned int Input);

    int Digits();
    int MaxDigits();

    MyFloat operator= (const char *Input);
    MyFloat operator= (const MyFloat &X);

    int operator== (const MyFloat &x);

    MyFloat operator+ (const MyFloat &X);
    int operator> (const MyFloat &x);

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &Out, const MyFloat & X);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream &In, MyFloat & X);

};

/********************* MyFloat Destructor ***************************
 Action: Deletes the memory being pointed to by the pointer Number;
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: none
 Returns: none
 Preconditions: Number has to be pointing at memory, or else error
        occur
 *******************************************************************/

MyFloat::~MyFloat()
{
    delete Number;
}

/********************* MyFloat Copy Constructor *********************
 Action: Initializes an object of MyFloat to be equal to any object being
        passed in via parameter list
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: const MyFloat & RHS - float being getting copied
 Returns: none
 Preconditions: must be of same data type - MyFloat
 *******************************************************************/

MyFloat::MyFloat(const MyFloat & RHS)
{
    MaxNumberOfDigits=RHS.MaxNumberOfDigits;
    NumberOfDigits=RHS.NumberOfDigits;

    Number = new (nothrow) char[RHS.NumberOfDigits+1]; //+1 for overflow

    if (Number != NULL)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=RHS.NumberOfDigits-1; ++i)
        {
            Number[i]=RHS.Number[i];
        }
    }

    else
        NumberOfDigits=0;
}

/********************* MyFloat Default Constructor *******************
 Action: Sets NumberOfDigits to 10 and places 0 in all elements of array
        being pointed to by *Number
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: none
 Returns: none
 Preconditions: none
 *******************************************************************/

MyFloat::MyFloat()
{
    MaxNumberOfDigits=DefaultSizeTen;//set MaxNumberOfDigits to default size of 10
    NumberOfDigits = 0;

    Number = new (nothrow) char[MaxNumberOfDigits+1]; //+1 for overflow

    if (Number != NULL)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=MaxNumberOfDigits; ++i)
        {
            Number[i]=0;
        }
    }
}

/********************* MyFloat Standard Constructor *******************
 Action: Sets NumberOfDigits to be equal to whatever user places inside of
        the paramter list
 Parameters:
    IN: unsigned int Input
    OUT: none
 Returns: none
 Preconditions: Input must be int and not negative
 *******************************************************************/

MyFloat::MyFloat(unsigned int Input)//Constructor that zeros out Number[] and NumberOfDigits
{
    MaxNumberOfDigits=Input;
    NumberOfDigits=0;

    Number = new (nothrow) char[MaxNumberOfDigits+1];

    if (Number != NULL)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=MaxNumberOfDigits; ++i)
        {
            Number[i]=0;
        }
    }
}

/********************* Digits() ********************************
 Action: Simply returns NumberOfDigits to main
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: none
 Returns: returns the NumberOfDigits
 Preconditions: none
 *******************************************************************/

int MyFloat::Digits()
{
    return NumberOfDigits;
}

/********************* MaxDigits() ********************************
 Action: Returns MAXDIGIT to main
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: none
 Returns: returns MAXDIGIT
 Preconditions: none
 *******************************************************************/

int MyFloat::MaxDigits()//Return MAXDIGIT or MaxNumberOfDigits?
{
    return MaxNumberOfDigits;
}

/********************* operator=() ********************************
 Action: Overloads the assignment operator to allow a string to be stored
    in the MyFloat data type, by dynamically allocating memory for a new
    array
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: Const char *Input, which points to the string being assigned to MyFloat
        data type
 Returns: *this

 Preconditions: Assumes incoming string was typed with leading '0' and '.',
    these are skipped when storing the string in the MyFloat data type
    Number isn't stored if decimal isn't present

 *Modified overloaded = function from solution set, since my original 
 function had some errors
 *******************************************************************/

MyFloat MyFloat::operator= (const char *Input)
{
    int CounterForInput = 0, CounterForNumber = 0, Length = 0, Temp = 0;

    NumberOfDigits = 0;


    /* SKIP PAST LEADING WHITESPACE, LEADING 0s, and Decimal */


    while ( (isspace(Input[CounterForInput]) || Input[CounterForInput] == '0') && Input[CounterForInput] != 0  )    //  Skip blanks and zeros
        ++CounterForInput;

    if ( Input[CounterForInput] != '.' )
        return *this;                 // Error, no decimal point

    ++CounterForInput;                            // Move to char after '.'


    /* CHECK TO SEE IF POINTER IS POINTING AT AN ARRAY WITH ENOUGH ROOM FOR COPY */


    Temp = CounterForInput;

    while (isdigit(Input[Temp])) // get length of incoming float without affecting CounterForInput
    {
        ++Length;
        ++Temp;
    }

    if (MaxNumberOfDigits<Length)
    {
        delete Number;
        Number = new (nothrow) char[Length+1];

        if (Number == NULL)
        {
            NumberOfDigits = 0;
            return *this;
        }
    }


    /* ASSIGN INPUT TO ARRAY BEING POINTED AT BY NUMBER */


    while ( CounterForNumber <= MaxNumberOfDigits && isdigit(Input[CounterForInput]) ) //  Copy rest of string
        Number[CounterForNumber++] = Input[CounterForInput++] - '0';

    NumberOfDigits = CounterForNumber;

    while ( CounterForNumber < MaxNumberOfDigits )       // Pad with trailing zeros
        Number[++CounterForNumber] = 0;

    return *this;
}

/********************* operator=() ********************************
 Action: Another Overloaded assignment operator to allow a MyFloat to be
    copied to another MyFloat, by dynamically allocating memory for a new
    array
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: Const MyFloat &X
 Returns: *this
 Preconditions: none
 *******************************************************************/

MyFloat MyFloat::operator= (const MyFloat &X)
{
    if (MaxNumberOfDigits<X.MaxNumberOfDigits)
    {
        delete Number;

        Number = new (nothrow) char [X.MaxNumberOfDigits+1];

        if (Number == NULL)
        {
            NumberOfDigits=0;
            return *this;
        }
    }

    NumberOfDigits = X.NumberOfDigits;
    MaxNumberOfDigits = X.MaxNumberOfDigits;

    for (int i=0; i<=MaxNumberOfDigits; i++)
    {
        Number[i] = X.Number[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

/********************* operator==() ********************************
 Action: Overloads the comparison operator to compare data members of
        two different objects of MyFloat
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: const MyFloat &x, which contains data members holding one float
 Returns: 1 if both MyFloat numbers are equal, 0 if they are different
 Preconditions: none
 *******************************************************************/

int MyFloat::operator== (const MyFloat &x)
{
    int Counter;

    if (NumberOfDigits>x.NumberOfDigits)
        Counter = NumberOfDigits;

    else
        Counter = x.NumberOfDigits;

    for (int i=0; i<=Counter || Number[i]; ++i)
    {
        if (x.Number[i]!=Number[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

/********************* operator+() ********************************
 Action: Overloads the addition operator to allow it to add two MyFloats
        together
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: MyFloat x, which contains data members holding one float
 Returns: MyFloat Storage back to main driver
 Preconditions: none
 *******************************************************************/

MyFloat MyFloat::operator+ (const MyFloat &X)
{
    int Carry=0;
    int Integer=0;
    int DifferenceInLength=0;
    int ForLoopCounter=0;
    MyFloat Storage;

    if (NumberOfDigits > X.NumberOfDigits)
    {
        Storage = *this;
        //just copy larger float over to storage so it is large enough to hold new number
        //new number will use the same ending numbers as the longest number as well

        DifferenceInLength = NumberOfDigits - X.NumberOfDigits;
        //Get the difference between the lengths of the two numbers, will be used in next for loop

        ForLoopCounter=NumberOfDigits - DifferenceInLength;
    }

    else
    {
        Storage = X;
        DifferenceInLength = X.NumberOfDigits - NumberOfDigits;
        ForLoopCounter=X.NumberOfDigits - DifferenceInLength;
    }

    for (int i=ForLoopCounter-1; i>=0; --i) //- 1 to work with Array style counting
    {
        Integer = ((X.Number[i]) + (Number[i]) + (Carry));

        Carry = 0;

        if (Integer>=10)
        {
            Carry = Integer/10;
            Integer %= 10;
        }

        Storage.Number[i] = Integer;

        Integer = 0;
    }

    if (NumberOfDigits>X.NumberOfDigits)
        Storage.NumberOfDigits = (NumberOfDigits);

    else
        Storage.NumberOfDigits = X.NumberOfDigits;//Storage.NumberOfDigits will be equal to the larger NumberOfDigits of the two floats being added

    return Storage;
}

/********************* operator>() ********************************
 Action: Overloads the greater than operator to allow two MyFloats to be
    compared
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: const MyFloat &x, which contains data members holding one float
 Returns: 0 if false, 1 if true (if calling object is greater than object
    being passed in)

 Preconditions: none
 *******************************************************************/

int MyFloat::operator> (const MyFloat &x)
{
    for (int i=0; i<=MaxNumberOfDigits; ++i)
    {
        if (Number[i]<x.Number[i])
            return 0;
        else if (Number[i]>x.Number[i])
            return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}

/********************* operator<<() ********************************
 Action: Overloads << operator to allow it to work on custom MyFloat
        data type
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: ostream &Out, const MyFloat & x
 Returns: Reference to ostream
 Preconditions: none
 *******************************************************************/

ostream & operator<< (ostream &Out, const MyFloat & X)
{
    Out << "0.";

    if (X.NumberOfDigits != 0)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=X.NumberOfDigits-1; ++j)
        {
            Out << (int) X.Number[j];
        }
    }

    else
        Out << "?";

    return Out;
}

/********************* operator>>() ********************************
 Action: Reads and stores the float typed in by the user using certain
    conditions.  Skips all leading whitespace and 0s, then stores any
    numbers after that.
 Parameters:
    IN: none
    OUT: istream &In, Myfloat & x
 Returns: reference to istream
 Preconditions: none
 *******************************************************************/

istream & operator>> (istream &In, MyFloat & X)
{
    int Counter=0;
    char Character;

    cin.ignore(); // clear newline from input buffer, my algorithm doesn't
                  // work if newline is in input buffer when entering function

    X.NumberOfDigits=0;

    cin.get(Character);

    while ((isspace(Character) || Character=='0') && (Character != '\n'))
        cin.get(Character);

    if (Character != '.')
        return In;

    cin.get(Character);

    while (isdigit(Character) && Counter<=X.MaxNumberOfDigits-1)
    {
        X.Number[Counter]= Character-'0';
        cin.get(Character);
        ++Counter;
    }

    cin.putback(Character);//puts back last character stored - newline in this case

    X.NumberOfDigits= Counter;

    for (; Counter<=X.MaxNumberOfDigits-1; ++Counter)
    {
        X.Number[Counter]=0;
    }

    cin.ignore(100, '\n');  // flush any extra numbers in input - mostly for when
                            // user types in a number longer than array can hold

    return In;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical assignment operator for class `C` returns `C&` - a reference to the object on the left-hand side of the assignment.

Yours, instead, returns a *copy* of that object, by value. It is that temporary copy that is then immediately destroyed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No they do not. Why do you ask? I'm not sure I quite follow what you are driving at with this line of inquiry.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do I? Color me dense, but I don't see where I say anything of the sort. The words "constructor" or "retunn" [sic] never once appear in my answer.

Comment: This sort of makes sense, by changing the return type both the prototype and function definition from MyFloat to MyFloat&, both the copy constructor function call and the destructor function call are eliminated from the process.

Though to be honest, I'm still a little unclear as to what's being destroyed (in the original code that returns it by value).  A copy of the object in the assignment operator?  Or the copy that is being returned?

Comment: I assume a copy is being made, then sent back to the place where the assignment operator was called.  This copy is then copied over to the LHS, then the RHS is then the one that is being passed into the destructor?

Comment: An overloaded operator is a function like any other, just with a fancy name. When you write `X = "0.12345"`, it's the same as writing `X.operator=("0.12345");`. Like any other function, it may return a value, which the caller is free to ignore. In your original code, the returned value is a temporary object of type `MyFloat`, copy-constructed from `X`. This temporary object is then automatically destroyed at the end of the full expression (at the semicolon) - that's what makes it temporary.